# How to handle scroll inside scroll in react-native

Tags: react-native

How do I do this?

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>            // Not actually present in the same component
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}         // as that of this ScrollView
                onTouchRecognized={()=>{parentScollView.lock()}}>
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

What is the right way of doing **`onTouchRecognized={()=>{parentScollView.lock()}`** ?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to do what's mentioned in [here](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/428), but how do I do that?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I have horizontal `FlatList` in `react-native-scrollable-tab-view`, `FlatList` is working fine, but I need to change scrollable tab when swiping left on `FlatList` and no item is left to scroll